# Xcode: how to work with library/framework conveniently while keeping code private towards others?

Tags: xcode, static-libraries

I have been following this tutorial: https://medium.com/better-programming/create-swift-5-static-library-f1c7a1be3e45

However, it is inconvenient to copy the new .a file every time I make a change to the library. What is the common setup during development of the static library? Do a "copy to iOS project folder" in the build script or linking the frameworks "Products" folder in the iOS project etc.?

During development, **Subprojects** seem to be a really useful way (https://www.raywenderlich.com/2658-creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial). However, copying the project to another computer renders it useless as it seems to rely on the Subproject and not e.g. cache the data from the last build.

The background is that I want to work with a client that I don't want to give access to my private API.

I am looking for a solution that lets me

- work on the project as well as the library conveniently (either by submodules or by having opened 2 Xcode windows at the time)
- commit changes to the Git repo (via the Xcode Source Control) and automatically have the compiled framework being pushed, too
- have my be able client to use my Project and work on the Project but only has access to the compiled library so he can't see what's inside it